# Firefox windowed fullscreen?

Tags: firefox, autohotkey

I would like to have a button for firefox which makes it go windowed fullscreen (i.e. show only the content area, no titlebar, menubar, tabs, addressbar).

I did have this implemented using autohotkey with something as simple as

```
WinGetPos, x, y, w, h
SendInput {F11}
WinMove, A,, x, y, w, h
```

however this does not work anymore for some reason. My current firefox version is Firefox Quantum 65.0.2 (64-Bit).
I didn't use the function for a while and just noticed this, so I'm not exactly sure at what point it stopped working, but it was at most a few months ago. I assume there was some automatic firefox update which did this.
Specifcally, while AHK still works for moving and resizing an active firefox window, it now has no effect on a fullscreen window..

My best idea for a workaround was to disable all of the unwanted bars in about:config, but I don't know if they are all in there or what the corresponding variables are (I only found browser.tabs.drawInTitlebar).
Also, editing the file where these are stored doesnt automatically update active windows, so I guess I would have to make a script that goes through all the setup manually each time I want to swap between normal/windowed FS mode, which sounds very annoying..

I did some googling but found nothing useful. Does anyone have an idea how one could do this? Some way to force it with AHK (would prefer this..), some javascript, .. ? I guess it would be possible to write an extension for this, but I don't know anything about writing firefox extensions unfortunately =(

Comment: You can try `ControlSend,, {F11}, ahk_exe firefox.exe`